# Passing a set of pointers to member functions of a template class

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, stdset

I have here a minimized version of code below, that won't compile.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
template<int D>
class Points{
public:
    std::vector<int> data;
    void func1()
    {
        // some operation on data which depends on D
        std::cout<<"Operation 1 which is " <<"D \n";
    }
    void func2()
    {
        // some operation on data which depends on D
        std::cout<<"Operation 2 which is " <<"D \n";
    }
    void execute_all(std::vector<void (Points::*)()> flist)
    {
        for (auto f: flist){
            (this->* f)();
        }
    }
};
template<int D>
using fptr = void (Points::*)();

int main()
{
    constexpr D = 2;
    Points p;
    std::set<fptr<D>> functionlist;
    functionlist.insert(&(Points<D>::func1));
    functionlist.insert(&(Points<D>::func2));
    p.execute_all(functionlist);
    return 0;
}
```

My intention is to group together function pointers, that I can pass to the member function in order to execute them together. In my intended code (not shown here) the "execute_all" happens in a deeply nested loop, with local arguments. I tried to run the above, even without a template class, but even that won't compile: `invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Points::func1()’`
Please help by pointing me to the issues with my code, and possibly providing a corrected version, that executes all functions func1 and func2 as intented.

Comment: What type of argument are you passing to the `execute_all` function? What is the type of argument it expects? Is the code you show us really a proper [mre]?

Comment: On a different note, get off the habit of passing containers as argument, and use iterators instead.

Comment: it must be `template<int D>using fptr = void (Points<D>::*)();` and your function expect a vector and receive a set, you must choose

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you give a one line code of how to pass iterators as argument in this scenario? If I use container reference, would that be better?

Comment: `template<It> void fun(It first, It end)`? Just like any function in the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fptr` needs to use `D` to say to what `Points` member functions the pointer is actually a pointer type for.

```cpp
template <int D>
using fptr = void (Points<D>::*)();
```

You are also mixing container types. You can't assign a `set` to a `vector`.

Fixed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <int D>
class Points {
public:
    std::vector<int> data;

    void func1() {
        // some operation on data which depends on D
        std::cout << "Operation 1 which is " << D << "D\n";
    }

    void func2() {
        // some operation on data which depends on D
        std::cout << "Operation 2 which is " << D << "D\n";
    }

    void execute_all(const std::vector<void (Points::*)()>& flist) {
        for (auto f : flist) {
            (this->*f)();
        }
    }
};

template <int D>
using fptr = void (Points<D>::*)();

int main() {
    constexpr int D = 2;                // int was missing here
    Points<D> p;                        // <D> was missing here
    std::vector<fptr<D>> functionlist;  // was a set
    functionlist.push_back(&Points<D>::func1);
    functionlist.push_back(&Points<D>::func2);
    p.execute_all(functionlist);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/76Yh13WaY)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <functional>

// Sample template class
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
// Example member function
void foo(T value) {
    std::cout << "foo: " << value << std::endl;
}
};

// Function that accepts a set of member function pointers
template <typename T>
void processMemberFunctionPointers(const std::set<void (MyClass<T>::*)(T)>& 
functionPointers, T value) {
MyClass<T> obj;

// Invoke each member function pointer in the set
for (auto functionPointer : functionPointers) {
    // Call the member function using the object
    (obj.*functionPointer)(value);
}
}

int main() {
// Create a set of member function pointers
std::set<void (MyClass<int>::*)(int)> functionPointers;

// Add member function pointers to the set
functionPointers.insert(&MyClass<int>::foo);

// Process the member function pointers
processMemberFunctionPointers(functionPointers, 42);

return 0;
}
```

Now, In this example, we have a template class MyClass with a member function foo. The processMemberFunctionPointers function accepts a set of member function pointers as its first parameter. It takes an additional parameter value which is passed to each member function during invocation.

In the main function, we create a set functionPointers to store the member function pointers of MyClass's member functions. We add a member function pointer &MyClass::foo to the set.

Finally, we call processMemberFunctionPointers with the set of member function pointers and a value of 42. The function iterates over each member function pointer in the set and invokes it on an instance of MyClass.